# Two Wordpress Installs -- Failed page on One Defaults to the Other

Tags: wordpress

I have hosting space at goDaddy that is shared between a couple domains.  Originally I had a single wordpress install in a sub folder.  Now I also have a wordpress install in the root directory also.  The wordpress that was installed first in the sub folder works if you go to the home page, but if you try to go to a different page or look at archived posts it looks for the page or posts on the wordpress blog installed in the root directory.  How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are your WordPress installs for separate domains?

Comment: Yep.  There is one install per domain.  The domain that points to the subdirectory doesn't technically have storage space.  It uses the space from the root domain.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the storage issue?  Why wouldn't you have storage?  Do you have your admin settings for the wordpress url and site url set correctly?

Comment: It isn't an issue.  I was just trying to make it clear that they share the same space.  There is one domain pointing to the root directory and that wordpress install, and one pointing to the subdirectory with the other wordpress install.

Comment: Try changing the permalinks to the default and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Changing the permalink setting doesn't modify any of the existing page links, or fix the problem.  Also a new web.config file is generated every time I go to the settings tab and that breaks my website.  Having a web.config file in addition to the root one creates issues.

Comment: Could you provide links to the two sites?

Comment: http://www.NathanTornquist.com is my site.  The other site is my father's.  You'll see it link back there if you click any of the page links in the navigation bar at the top.

Comment: The problem is in the way url's are directed.  You may have missed a directory in one of your paths in your config file.  I am not familiar with web.config, but posting your code may help.

Comment: When I have a web.config file in place I get a 400 error.  GoDaddy told me to delete the web.config file from the subdirectory and have it just default to the one in the root.